# try catch on looping (differnet between InputMismatchException and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, inputmismatchexception

I have this code

```
package example;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rep;
    int[] arraya = new int[2];
    do {
        try {
            rep = 0;
            System.out.print("input col :");
            int kol = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("input value :");
            int val = input.nextInt();
            arraya[kol] = val;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("input must integer");
            rep = 1;
            input.next();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("out of range");
            rep = 1;
        }
    } while (rep == 1);
}
}
```

Why must I add `input.next();` in `catch(InputMismatchException e);` to avoid endless looping?

Why in `catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e);` do not need `input.next();` to avoid endless looping?

In `catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e);`, looping runs well without `input.next();` why it is different from `catch(InputMismatchException e);` ?

Comment: You shouldn't catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should fix the bug that causes it.

Comment: @EJP thanks for your reply, i made that code to know what the different between `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `InputMismatchException` why they treated different in looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you enter a non-integer character, `int kol = input.nextInt();` will *not* wait for the user to enter an `int` again, it'll keep trying to read the character that was entered previously since it wasn't consumed.

If you enter an out-of-bounds `int`, it *will* be consumed, and the next `int` be read in the next iteration.